# Are there any keyboard dictation options comparable to FN+FN on MacOS for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, input-devices, accessibility

I'm currently trying to get someone with Dyslexia to try using Ubuntu as a main OS.
They're used to the keyboard dictation option available on MacOS that allows you to type anywhere with your mic by pressing the FN key twice.

So far I have found text editors that offer a similar feature that's limited to being used within the editor. Not particularly helpful for someone who has issues with spelling and using a keyboard quickly.

I also found a method using android keyboard dictation combined with KDE Connect. This would technically work, but it requires having an android phone at the ready.

Is there any software available that could supplement this functionality?